# How to switch from div to table layout for Symfony2 forms?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I see [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_table_layout.html.twig) that there is a possible twig template for rendering a form into table based html. I am wondering though how to change the default layout for one form, from the default div based html to table based. According to the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) it is possible to do:

```
{% form_theme form 'path_to_template.html.twig' %}
```

How do I include that twig template, I tried things like:

```
{% form_theme form 'Twig:Form:form_table_layout.html.twig' %}
```

but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay found it, you only have to use

```
{% form_theme form 'form_table_layout.html.twig' %}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the table layout in your whole application you can save yourself from having to add `form_theme` in every template of yours by setting your default layout like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources: ['form_table_layout.html.twig']
```

See [Symfony2 Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#twig)